# after my function calculates a value it does not get saved

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to make a simple attack on health for a small game. so the function calculates the damage but when I print the health after the function it is still the same.`so I am trying to make this ghoul.name to print out the difference

```
if (option == 1)
{
    attack(ghoul.health, player.attackPower );

}
 cout<<ghoul.Name<<endl;

    int attack(int x, int y){
    x -= y;
    cout << "You have stuck your foe for " << y << " dmg." <<endl;
    cout << endl;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to make a [mre]

Comment: Have you learned about how variables are passed by value? (Such that modifying `x` inside the function has no effect outside of it.) Have you learned about return values? (Such that calling `attack` without saving the returned value anywhere will simply not use the returned value.)

Comment: Reread your C++ learning material on "pass by value", "pass by reference", and just "references". This is a case for using the latter two concepts.

Comment: "pro" tip: dont use endl unless flushing the stream after every cout is what you want (99% of the time it's not)

Comment: also this is more "advanced" but that's exactly why attack() should be marked with "[[nodiscard]]", you forgot to use the return value of attack() and assign it to ghoul.health

Comment: @Yamahari: But note that if stdout is connected to an interactive terminal (usually this is determined by `isatty`) then it's going to be line buffered and `\n` will cause flushing just as much as `std::endl`

Answer (score 1):

Either assign the result of `attack` to `ghoul.health`:

```
ghoul.health = attack(ghoul.health, player.attackPower);
```

Or take health by reference:

```
int attack(int& x, int y);
```